# Don't create default cluster in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How do I prevent postgresql-9.4 from creating default cluster (main)? I have Ubuntu 14.04, use aptitude and postresql official repository. I'm using ansible to control multiple servers and want to create my own clusters.

Comment: How do you see Ubuntu providing an answer to this? This question, to me, seems to be about database management. That is independent of the operating system and (again to me): http://dba.stackexchange.com/ seems more appropriate.

Comment: The package was prepared for Ubuntu. The problem concerns Ubuntu and it's packaging tools. I didn't have the same problem on Red Hat .  Postgres itself is working properly.

Comment: I don't think you can prevent the default cluster but you can drop it immediately after install, see `pg_dropcluster`

Comment: I finally found a solution to this problem. It is specific to Ubuntu and concerns settings of wrappers for Postgres in Ubuntu (they are also available in Debian-based distributions). Please open the question so that I could provide more detailed answer.

Comment: @owca I have reopened the question, thank you for your patience. Please post your answer! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing which is responsible for automatic creation of main cluster is package postgresql-commons. The purpose of this package is to allow multiple clusters running on multiple versions of PostgreSQL on the same machine. You can have PostgreSQL in different versions installed at the same time. Each can manage multiple clusters.

Postgresql-commons has configuration files in **/etc/postgresql-common/**. The one which is especially interesting is **createcluster.conf**. Here is its content:

```
# Default values for pg_createcluster(8)
# Occurrences of '%v' are replaced by the major version number,
# and '%c' by the cluster name. Use '%%' for a literal '%'.

# Create a "main" cluster when a new postgresql-x.y server package is installed
#create_main_cluster = true

# Default start.conf value, must be one of "auto", "manual", and "disabled".
# See pg_createcluster(8) for more documentation.
#start_conf = 'auto'

# Default data directory.
#data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/%v/%c'

# Default directory for transaction logs
# Unset by default, i.e. pg_xlog remains in the data directory.
#xlogdir = '/var/lib/postgresql/xlog/%v/%c/pg_xlog'

# Options to pass to initdb.
#initdb_options = ''

# The following options are copied into the new cluster's postgresql.conf:

# Enable SSL by default (using the "snakeoil" certificates installed by the
# ssl-cert package, unless configured otherwise here)
ssl = on

# Put stats_temp_directory on tmpfs
stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/%v-%c.pg_stat_tmp'

# Add prefix to log lines
log_line_prefix = '%%t [%%p-%%l] %%q%%u@%%d '
```

To prevent it from creating main cluster you have to install postgresql-commons, uncomment line with **create_main_cluster**, set it to **false** and then install PostgreSQL in desired version.

Comment: Saved me like 7 years later haha. Too bad I found this after COUNTLESS trial and error attempts...